# How do I count number of items per tag in SQL, when tags is an array of strings?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table that looks like this:
`ItemID, Tags`

ItemID is a string, Tags is an array of strings.

The DB engine is Presto: https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/index.html

I have to return a count of ItemIDs for each tag but I'm kind of getting stuck. My first approach was to extract the Tags and create an unique list and then I was hoping that through some join magic I'd be able to GROUP BY and then count.

How should I approach this? I don't have a lot of experience with SQL arrays

I also can't figure out how to use UNNEST to create rows and then a table out of this:

```
SELECT filter(flatten(array_agg(split(tags, ','))), x -> x != '')
FROM my_items
```

This returns an array of unique tags and apparently with UNNEST this can be turned into a set of rows but I've had no luck so far converting it into that. Tried stuff like:

```
SELECT UNNEST(above subquery) FROM MY_ITEMS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want an [`unnest()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) and aggregation:

```
select t.tag, count(*)
from my_items i cross join
     unnest(split(i.tags, ',')) t(tag)
group by t.tag;
```

Comment: I can't quite follow your code, does unnest create a new table you named t?

Comment: @oblio . . . `t` is not a table.  It is a table alias which is assigned to the result of the `unnest()`.

Comment: Ah, yes it does, silly me: "UNNEST can be used to expand an ARRAY or MAP into a relation." -> "relation", yes, it acts like a table, after all, relational logic :-)
My bad about the terminology, it's not a "table" in the naive sense I used it.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure because I couldn't try it on my Presto (yet). But `cardinality` function might work.

```
cardinality(x) → bigint -- Returns the cardinality (size) of the array x.
```

From Presto docs here - https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html